# Insect decline and CO2 concentration

Tags: entomology, respiration

In the UK, where I live, for several years we have had cold dry springs which seems to delay appearance of insects. So irratic weather could cause species to emerge out of sync with their food species and that is an example of how climate change could lead to decline. But insect decline is occurring globally and not all areas have the same factors that could contribute like use of pesticides, habitat destruction etc.

One factor that is more global is the increase of CO2. Could it be that because insects rely on diffusion through tracheae to respire they are more affected, at part of their life cycle, by increased CO2? you might not think that the concentration of atmospheric CO2 at 470ppm and a 47% increase since pre-industrial era would be enough to make a difference but has anyone done the experiments to check?

Comment: Interesting idea - what did your searches of the literature tell you?

Comment: First question: is there a way to dissociate this from pesticide use? second question: is there a way to dissociate this from temperature? e.g. recent studies consider both of these to be major contributors to recent declines https://beyondpesticides.org/dailynewsblog/2022/05/climate-change-and-industrial-agriculture-are-supercharging-the-insect-apocalypse/

Comment: @bob1 I dont have access to journals but I found no mention of it in general web seach

Comment: Looks from your reference that CO2 concentration might not be significant